# UIWebView dont bounce and scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I m building a very simple ios native app with two view controllers referenced from a tab bar

both are webview, one is local html and other is loaded from url

for some reason the local webview does not allow scrolling and I cant figure out why.

I checked the settings in the storyboard and all the settings are the same

Use auto layout, user interaction enabled, mode aspect fit

I even tried to fix the issue by code , but adding this code to my view controller has not effect

```
webDisplay.scrollView.bounces = YES;
webDisplay.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Any ideas of what s wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent view was missing the user interaction enabled flag.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can try

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

f you want to check for being on iOS 4 or 5, you can test for UIWebView responding to the scrollView property getter:

```
if ([webView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)]) {
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
} else {
    webView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    webView.bounces = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (id subview in webView.subviews)

if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])

((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = YES;

((UIScrollView *)subview). scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: I tried this. put a breakpoint to verify I enter in the bounces/scrollEnabled block, but the issue is still present ;(